# Orbeon forms 4.8 - Autocomplete field remove value if there is space character entered on the end

Tags: autocomplete, orbeon

I have a problem regarding entering values into an autocomplete field.

When a word is entered and it ends with a space, the value is removed from the field when leaving that field. The value is removed, even though it exists in autocomplete suggestions:

[image: You can see gif image how it works now]

Comment: Lazar, I answered your question below, and you'll let me know if I misunderstood anything, or if you think that the current behavior ought to be improved in any way. -Alex

Comment: Thank you @avernet for answer, I understood it clearly. But still i need to enter values that are not in suggestions. For example, in street field or house number for that street. Someone created a service which adds entered value alongside all suggestions before I entered the project, but when space character is entered it recognize only value without spaces even if value with spaces is provided to Orbeon server. So, my question now would be, how Orbeon calls that service behind the scenes? Url for that service is added in backoffice...

Answer (score 0):

The autocomplete implements a "closed selection": users can only select values that are in a predefined "itemset"; they can't enter a new value. Should they try to enter a value that doesn't exist in the itemset, upon leaving the field, that value is removed, to make it clear to users that the value wasn't accepted.

Case and spacing matters, so if users enter a value with an additional space at the end, it is considered to be a different value, and thus, on leaving the field, it is removed, which explains the behavior you're seeing.

Comment: See also this [RFE](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1433) for an improved autocomplete control.

Comment: Thanks avernet for explanation, but this is not exactly answer I was hoping for, because to be exact i need to enter values not provided by autocomplete. For example street, or house number.

Comment: @LazarBlanuša In that case, I am afraid the autocomplete isn't the right component for that. We have an [open selection](https://doc.orbeon.com/form-runner/component/open-select1.html) control, but this is since 2016.1, and uses radio buttons. Would you be able to upgrade to a newer version? If are, would this component work for you?

Comment: And there is no way to change it's default behaviour. I can't access that code?

Comment: You can certainly change the code. Look for `autocomplete.xbl` in the jars inside your war. You can change that file, and other files in the same directory, and this in place, even without having to recompile Orbeon Forms. But the logic is pretty intricate, so excpect this be somewhat of a puzzler ;).